# Display procedurally generated object in the editor

Tags: godot

I'm working on a project where I'm procedurally assembling a world out of the blocks based on the OpenSimplexNoise object. It is done by adding the child nodes inside the `_ready` function. It works well and generated level is playable, but I would like to preview it without lunching a game. **Is it somehow possible to do so?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run code in the Godot editor ​by making [`tool`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/misc/running_code_in_the_editor.html#what-is-tool) scripts.

Simply add the `tool` keyword at the start of a script so it is allowed to run on the editor.

---

However, you probably don't want every function or every part of the code to run on the editor. You can detect if your code is running on the editor by checking `Engine.editor_hint`.

So you can add this code at the start of a `func`:

```
    if Engine.editor_hint:
        return
```

Which prevents the rest of the `func` from running on the editor.

Or do the opposite:

```
    if not Engine.editor_hint:
        return
```

Which prevents the rest of the `func` from running outside of the editor.

---

You also need to be aware that the changes the code makes to the scene… Are changes made to the scene. This includes adding nodes and changed properties.

For the added nodes you are likely to not need any special care, since usually you would not be setting the [`owner`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-property-owner) of the nodes, and thus those nodes would not persist with the scene.

Yet, you need to be careful with properties. *If you were making and addon you could add entry to the undo history.*

---

I presume you will want code to run when your `OpenSimplexNoise` changes. All `Resource` types, such as `OpenSimplexNoise` have a `"changed"` signal that you can connect to, and will notify when it changes. *For people making a custom resource type, know that you need to emit the signal manually form your code.*

And, I presume, you would only want to do that in the editor. And you are going to need to handle removing the old nodes and adding new ones, or have a way for them to be reconstructed for the new noise.

You can start by moving the logic out of `_ready` to another `func`. Then have `_ready` call that `func`, only when the code is not running in the editor. Then you can connect the `"changed"` signal to that new `func`, so it runs every time it changes. Which also means it should start with the cleanup code.

---

*By the way, what I described here is also the foundation for making addons. So I'll encourage you to look into that. For example it is possible to extend the UI of the editor.*